# Wifi hotspot with redirect to HTML

Tags: windows-10, wifi, router, hotspot

I'm trying to create a wifi hotspot in windows 10 that redirects the connected devices to a specific HTML page, hosted on the pc. I can create the hotspot. Is there a way to force a HTML page load, like some routers do?

The plan is:

1- The user will connect to the pc wifi hotspot.

2- The user device will load a HTML page hosted on the pc.

3- The user will download files through the links on the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do that is to install any DNS server. [This article](https://superuser.com/questions/337763/is-there-a-good-dns-server-i-can-install-on-windows-7-for-a-lan) can help to choise one. After that you can redirect all DNS requests to your PC. However it does not ptotect from opening web page by its IP.

The other way is to have Proxy on your PC that will redirect all traffic.